# Getting Jenkins to build different flavors of the same project

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle

I'm using Jenkins to build our companies Android application. In the gradle.build file, I have specified two separate types of build, debug, and production.

```
buildTypes {
    //TODO fix this so that signing works with release version
    debug {
        buildConfigField "boolean", "RELEASE", "false"
    }
    release {
        buildConfigField "boolean", "RELEASE", "true"
    }
}
```

How can I manually trigger Jenkins to build the release version?

Thanks,
-Mark

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a [parameterized build](https://baeldung-cn.com/ops/jenkins-parameterized-builds) - the parameter value will be available as an environment variable that you can test in your build file.

Comment: The specified link corrupted!

Answer (score 2):

Specifying a `buildType` additionally creates a task named `assemble<buildTypeName>`. If you only want to build the release version simply call the `assembleRelease` task.

Answer (score 0):

The solution needs jenkins plugin and gradle script!
After set flavor in the gradle script, you must go to the jenkins web application.
In the jenkins after click on the "configure" option in the project folder, choice the "General" tab.
You can add Parameter to this tab by clicking on the "Add Parameter" Button.
If you don't have this option, probably you needs install appropriate plugins.

[image]

You can add two "Choice Parameter" one of them for flavor and another for build variant like release or debug.

after adding "Choice Parameter" you can specified choices like "Release" , "Debug" and so on.

[image]

Finally in the "Build" tab in the "Invoke Gradle Script" select "Use Gradle Wrapper" radio button and past command bellow in the "Tasks" field :

```
clean assemble$MARKETS$BUILD_VARIANTS
```

As you can see in the picture follow :

[image]

Now you can choice flavor and build variant for build task!